# vuejs will not scroll to top of div on form error

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, scrolltop

I have 2 components on the same page both with a form.  I'm using Vue.js 2.6

The second form has a submit button and when clicked emits a property. The first form is listening for that property and acts on it once received which all works fine. This form hat makes an ajax request to validate a form which also works.

What I am having a problem with is if there are erros in the form, scroll to the top of the form and the submit button is way down in the page.

There are no console errors and all the valiation messages are shown but the form will NOT scroll to the top.

I think the problem lies in here

```
this.$nextTick(() => {
    this.$refs.notice.scrollTop = 0;
});
```

I have tried all the answers i could find on SO but nothing works

This is the first form

```
<template>
    <form id="contact-form" @submit.prevent="submit" ref="notice">
        <div class="card mb-4 border-0">
            <div class="notice notice-danger" v-show="errored">
                <strong>Error</strong> There are errors in the form!!
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12">
                    <div class="form-group floating-label-form-group controls">
                        <label>Contact Name</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Contact Name" id="contact" v-model="fields.contact" v-on:change="contactChange">
                        <div v-if="errors && errors.contact" class="text-danger">{{ errors.contact[0] }}</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-12">
                    <div class="form-group floating-label-form-group controls">
                        <label>Telephone</label>
                        <input type="tel" class="form-control" placeholder="Telephone (optional)" id="telephone" v-model="fields.telephone" v-on:change="telephoneChange">
                        <div v-if="errors && errors.telephone" class="text-danger">{{ errors.telephone[0] }}</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-12">
                    <div class="form-group floating-label-form-group controls">
                        <label>Email Address</label>
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" id="email" v-model="fields.email" v-on:change="emailChange">
                        <div v-if="errors && errors.email" class="text-danger">{{ errors.email[0] }}</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</template>
<script>
export default {
    data: function() {
        return {
            errors: {},
            errored: false,
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        this.$root.$on('checkFormsValid', (customer) => {
            this.errors = {};
            this.errored = false;

            axios.post('/some/url', this.fields).then(response => {
                this.$root.$emit('validated', response.data.customer);
            }).catch(error => {
                if (error.response.status === 422) {
                    this.errors = error.response.data.errors || {};
                    this.$root.$emit('errors', this.errors);
                    this.errored = true;

                    this.$nextTick(() => {
                        this.$refs.notice.scrollTop = 0;
                    });
                }
            });
        })
    },
    methods: {
        contactChange: function() {
            delete this.errors.contact;
        },
        telephoneChange: function() {
            delete this.errors.telephone;
        },
        emailChange: function() {
            delete this.errors.email;
        },
    }
}
</script>
```

and a slimmed down second form

```
<template>
    <form id="payment-form" ref="form" action="/checkout" method="POST" class="uk-padding">
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block" @click.prevent="okToSend()">
            Click me
        </button>
    </form>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                customer: '',
                loading: false,
            }
        },
        mounted() {
            this.$root.$on('validated', (customer) => {
                // do something
            })
        },
        methods: {
            okToSend: function() {
                this.$root.$emit('checkFormsValid', this.customer)
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Could you provide a screenshot of the form? It seems that you try to change scrollTop property of the wrong element. If the ref element which is the first form does not have scrollbar visible which means is not scrollable then you should change scrollTop of the parent element which is responsible for scrolling.

If thing I assume above is correct then you should do it like this: ``window.scrollTo( this.$refs.notice.offsetTop) // if window has a scrollbar.``

Answer (score 0):

Open dev tools and find out the exact div that is generating the scroll bar;  Then modify that element's scroll property.

You can also simply ensure a specific element is visible using a function such as this:

```js
function scrollToView(element){
    var offset = element.offset().top;
    if(!element.is(":visible")) {
        element.css({"visibility":"hidden"}).show();
        var offset = element.offset().top;
        element.css({"visibility":"", "display":""});
    }

    var visible_area_start = $(window).scrollTop();
    var visible_area_end = visible_area_start + window.innerHeight;

    if(offset < visible_area_start || offset > visible_area_end){
         // Not in view so scroll to it
         $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: offset - window.innerHeight/3}, 1000);
         return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```